# Does Ubuntu One sync only the changed parts of a file?

Tags: ubuntu-one

Are there plans to get U1 syncing only changes in files? It seems like anytime I listen to a sync'd song, it re-uploads the whole song instead of just the (very small) part where Banshee incremented the listens count and what ever else happens when I listen.

If I remember correctly, Dropbox handles this more gracefully. Does anyone have any answer about plans like this for U1?

Comment: sounds like a wishlist bug to me, but I could be wrong.

Comment: That very well could be, but I was wondering if anyone knew anything beyond "request it" before I requested it ... I also thought I read something about this quite a while ago, but I can't seem to find whatever it was that I read.

Comment: You can make Banshee track its listens counters internally (without writing them to the files) if you want to prevent this for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu One doesn't sync changes, but uploads whole file instead, no matter how small the change is. It's because of Amazon S3 protocol on which Ubuntu One is built on.

Comment: This is very unfortunate. It would save an awful lot of bandwidth for everyone involved if this could be resolved at some point.

Comment: I don't think it can be S3's fault, because Dropbox also uses S3: https://www.dropbox.com/help/7

Comment: It is and it isn't. Its correct that S3 does not support uploads of ["partial" files (ranges):](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=183373) BUT dropbox gets around this by Not uploading directly to S3 but instead to servers they run in AMazons EC2 cloud and and they then store the data into S3.

Answer (score 1):

If this was resolved Ubuntu One could save a lot of money every month.  Imagine the reduction in bandwidth Ubuntu would have to pay, and at 10 cents a GB it would add up.